# Checkbox in Javascript/Html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function checkForm(form)
    {
        if(!form.terms.checked){
        alert("Please indicate that you accept");
        forms.terms.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

    }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this);" action="www.google.com">
<p><input type="checkbox" name="terms"> I accept</p>
<p><input class="button" type="submit" value="Continue" ></p>
</form>
```

Hello I'm trying to add a checkbox that you have to check in order to continue. It pops op correctly when you click on the button without checking the box; however, it is still take you to the website. I want to keep asking to check the box before taking the user to the website. Could you guys give me a hand?  I try adding it after the return true between { } but it doesn't seems to work. My knowledge in javascript is very basic.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you have the JavaScript placed inside of your DOM? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: even when you click without checking the box it takes you. thats the problem

Comment: the problem is with focus see the console I removed it and it worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a little typo in your focus code (you typed `forms` instead of `form`). Here's the correct code.

```
function checkForm(form)
{
    if(!form.terms.checked){
        alert("Please indicate that you accept");
        form.terms.focus(); // corrected "form" instead of "forms"
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df51waLu/2/)

Comment: plus one for the sharp eye

Comment: damnit, I just wanted to point this out also. :D  you get an upvote now, for beeing faster. I salute you! :)

Comment: Damn, what an eye bro! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes with the focus on the input checkbox. Please change your Javascript code to

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function checkForm(form)
  {
     if(!form.terms.checked){
       return false;
      }
       return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of the button from submit to button and fire the evaluation function on the click event. If the checkbox is check then you submit the form.

(also added http:// on the href attribute)

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function checkForm(button)
{
    var form = button.form;
    if(!form.terms.checked)
    {
        alert("Please indicate that you accept");
        form.terms.focus();         
    }
    else
    {
        form.submit();
    }

}
</script>

<form action="http://www.google.com">
<p><input type="checkbox" name="terms"> I accept</p>
<p><input class="button" type="button" value="Continue" onclick="checkForm(this)" ></p>
</form>
```